# Windows phone 8.1 to Universal App

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am working on a Windows phone 8.1 application which consists of mainly a silverlight proect for the UI and a lot of other WINRT projects. The Silverlight project does the bulk of the work in displaying the data to the user and the WinRT project does all the major activities like pushing to the content to the server..

I would like to use the same WINRT projects in my Windows 8.1 application. Hence i am planning to use Universal apps to have a shared library and have different UI for both but use the bulk of the WINRT stuff for the same backend related activites.

I see that for windows phone 8.1 applciations(on silverlight) there are no templates like panorama etc...is there a work around or a best practice for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been renamed to [Hub](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn632424.aspx) to support both Windows and Windows Phone.